# changing java's .class file without recompiling

Tags: java

is there any way to do the following. so i have a project.jar file, inside it i need to modify the string passed to some method of let's say classA.class. for example, let's say this classA.class has a method named

```
change(String a, String b)
```

what i all want is to do the following as the first line of the code inside this method as follows:

```
a = a + "hi";
```

i want to modify the .class file directly, without needing to recompile everything again. then after that i would update the jar file with the new class file. is it possible? if yes can anyone show an example? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why compile time and not changing the behaviour run-time? That way you could at least upgrade the jar when necessary. AspectJ can do both run-time and compile time weaving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible with byte code editors. Commonly you can use [`aspectj`](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) together with compile time weaving to modify a class file. You can also use libraries such as [`BCEL`](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/manual.html), [`cglib`](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) etc.

However, for the use case you are describing you typically don't need to edit a class file. You can just wrap your object in a [`proxy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) or modify it's behaviour using [AoP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) style of programming (as supported by e.g., `aspectj`)

Answer (score 1):

There are tools to manipulate byte code dynamically, such as ASM: http://asm.ow2.org/

Answer (score 0):

another way could be instrumentation. when you are loading the class you could manipulate the bytecode before using it. there are some good libraries for this, for example javassist from jboss. i think aspectJ works similar.

but why you want to change the bytecode, compile it and add it to a jar file again? are you needing the source code? perhaps you could use some de-compiler to get the source code, if you need it. a good tool is http://java.decompiler.free.fr/.